# Select element is not appending addEventListener

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a select element and add an 'input' event to it. Everything with JavaScript as showed below:

```js
function showSelectedOption(str) {
  alert(str);
}

var list = document.createElement("select");
list.id = "listId";
list.addEventListener('input', showSelectedOption(this.selectedIndex));

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "none";
  option.text = "text";
  list.appendChild(option);
}

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

However, when I inspect the element the input event is not appended.

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this work by using `setAttribute` instead and set the value of the `oninput` attribute to be the string (not the function) `showSelectedOption(this.selectedIndex)`.

```js
function showSelectedOption(str) {
  alert(str);
}

var list = document.createElement("select");
list.id = "listId";
list.setAttribute('oninput', "showSelectedOption(this.selectedIndex)");

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  option.value = "none";
  option.text = "item"+i;
  list.appendChild(option);
}

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 2):

A couple of issues.

You are not binding the `showSelectedOption` function, you instead call it and use its returned value (*which is `undefined`*) as the event handler.

So pass `showSelectedOption` without calling it.

Then you will have to find the `selectedIndex` of that element inside the method, by using the `event` passed to the function when the `input` event is triggered.

```js
function showSelectedOption(event) {
  var element = event.target,
      index = element.selectedIndex,
      value = element.options[index].value;

  alert(value);
}

var list = document.createElement("select");

list.id = "listId";
list.addEventListener('input', showSelectedOption);

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var option = document.createElement("option");
  
  option.value = "none";
  option.text = "text";
  list.appendChild(option);
}

document.body.appendChild(list);
```

Comment: Hi, it works. Thanks! But when we inspect the element we cannot see the 'oninpu't event at the element's attributes list

Comment: @Jas indeed, when using `addEventListener` it does not show on the inspector as `oninput`. Keep in mind though that you can only add one `oninput` on each element while you can add as many handlers as you want with `addEventListener`